# Can low rank/low variable first order logic formulas approximate higher order one?

Tags: graph-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory, approximation-theory

I say a formula $\Phi$ labels a model $g$ as $1$ iff $g \models \Phi$. Otherwise the formula labels the model $-1$. I use $\Phi[g]$ to denote the label that $\Phi$ assigns to $g$.I also assume that $g$ is sampled from some distribution $D$.

My goal is to understand if any FOL formula, labelling graphs of a fixed order $n$, sampled from some distribution $D$, can be approximated by a formula with lower rank or lower number of variables. I state my problem more formally in the following:

Let us assume a function-free first order logic language on graphs of size $n$, i.e. $n$ nodes. Let $G_n$ denote the set of such graphs. Let $D$ be some distribution. For any first order logic sentence $\Phi_{v,k}$, with $v$ variables and quantifier rank $k$, can I have another formula $\Phi'_{v',k'}$, where $v' \leq v$ and $k' \leq k$, and either $v' < v$ or $k' < k$, such that:

$$\mathbb{E}_{g \sim D }\big[\Phi_{v,k}[g] \times \Phi'_{v',k'}[g]\big] > \gamma $$

For some $\gamma \in [0,1]$. Also, assume that $v,k << n$.

My motivation is that this could help, some practical low order approximations of complex structures on graphs. But I am not sure how to attack this, I tried thinking of gaifman normal form, but it adds quantifiers for the normal form, so did not go into much details.

Comment: Is the expected value of the *product* of the truth values really what you want? Based on your motivation, I was expecting that you would look at the probability that the two true values are equal.

Comment: Asking the approximating formula to work for *all* distributions on $G_n$ seems unrealistic. If $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ differ on a single graph $G$, can't we take the distribution $D$ that produces $G$ with probability $1$? Then $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ disagree with probability $1$ on graphs samples from $D$. Last clarification: you want to work with graphs of a fixed size $n$, rather than allowing $n$ to vary?

Comment: @AlexKruckman about the truth values being same, I am sorry, my bad, there was a typo. Now the formula labels a model $-1$ if it does not satisfy the formula. Although, this is stronger than truth values being same

Comment: About the distributions, this is standard assumption in Probabilistically Approximately Correct Learning, also note that you don't really have complete freedom with $\Phi'$, you have to stay within the number of variables and quantifiers. Also, about $n$, assume $n >> v,k$, but finite and fixed apriori.

Comment: What is the standard assumption in PAC Learning that you're referring to? My argument is that *no* $\Phi'$ will work for every distribution, unless $\Phi$ happens to be equivalent to a simpler formula (one with fewer variables or smaller quantifier rank). Let me be more clear about it, and you can tell me what I'm misunderstanding. Suppose $\Phi$ is not equivalent (on graphs of size $n$) to any simpler formula. Let $\Phi'$ be a simpler formula. I claim that $\Phi'$ doesn't approximate $\Phi$. Since $\Phi$ and $\Phi'$ are not equivalent, there is a graph $G$ of size $n$ which they disagree on.

Comment: Now letting $D$ be the distribution which produces $G$ with probability $1$, we get $\mathbb{E}_{g\sim D}[\Phi[g]\times \Phi'[g]] = -1$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry for the deleted comments, I realise now that the question was not communicating what I meant by "any distribution" . Note that once a distribution and a formula labelling it is given (latently), I want to create an approximation for that fixed distribution and the formula --- the distribution does not change anymore, I have changed the wording of the question to make this more clear. But this construction supposed to work for "any distributions".

Comment: Also, the argument of labelling only 1 graph as  true, will most likely not work, as you can still get a $\gamma$ close to 1, by making $\Phi'$ label everything 0. You can ignore the "(latently)" in the last comment

Comment: Ok, the question makes more sense now.